# Getting a response from an Azure insert

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I have inherited the development of an iOS app that connects to an Azure mobile service, and I'm stuck on getting an acceptable response from my insert operations. Specifically I want to get back the object that was inserted, or at least the value of its id field, from a Custom API script that the previous developer on this project created.

A truncated version of the Custom API script I'm using looks like:

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {
    var mssql = request.service.mssql;
    var sql = "INSERT INTO Reservation (<field names>)" +
    " VALUES (<field values>); "
    +"SELECT id FROM Reservation WHERE __updatedAt = (SELECT MAX(__updatedAt) FROM Reservation);"; 

    mssql.query(sql, {
        success: function(results) {

            console.log("after post - results = " + results);

            response.send(statusCodes.OK, results);
        }
    });
};
```

When I run the iOS app and post a Reservation (using the AFNetworking class to communicate with the server), I get back a response object with an empty array. Furthermore, inspecting the Azure log for the results of the console.log statement in my function, I see two results: "after post - results = [object Object]" and "after post - results =".

I'm clearly doing something wrong, but I don't understand what. I have tried a number of other different approaches, all with similarly unsatisfactory results. For what it's worth, the "get" script for this class works just fine. I wonder if anybody can help me get this "post" script right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted in your logs, the success callback for the `mssql.query` call is being called twice - since you have two statements in your query. When you first call `response.send`, that's the response which is sent back to the client. The first callback will contain the results for the `INSERT` call, which is not what you want to return. You should use a flag to indicate which result you're receiving, and only return if it's the one you want:

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {
    var mssql = request.service.mssql;
    var sql = "INSERT INTO Reservation (<field names>)" +
    " VALUES (<field values>); "
    +"SELECT id FROM Reservation WHERE __updatedAt = (SELECT MAX(__updatedAt) FROM Reservation);"; 

    var firstCall = true;
    mssql.query(sql, {
        success: function(results) {
            console.log("after post - results = " + results);
            if (firstCall) {
                firstCall = false;
            } else {
                response.send(statusCodes.OK, results);
            }
        }
    });
};
```